# What special meaning does an equal-sign have in zsh?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

In my zsh script, I had a line

```
echo some text ================================
```

To my surprise, an error message was issued for this line:

```
zsh: =============================== not found
```

Experimenting from the command line, I found that the shell gets upset when there is an equal sign:

```
$ echo =z
zsh: z not found
```

But here, we have:

```
$ echo =echo
/usr/bin/echo
```

From this observation, it looks, as if

```
=XXX
```

would be interpreted like

```
$(which XXX)
```

However, I didn't find anything about this "substitution" in the zsh manpage. Where is this piece of magic described?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion):

> 14.7.3 ‘=’ expansion
>
> If a word begins with an unquoted ‘=’ and the EQUALS option is set,
>   the remainder of the word is taken as the name of a command. If a
>   command exists by that name, the word is replaced by the full pathname
>   of the command.

And [here](https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/45-ZSH-Gem-11-Path-and-filename-expansion.html) in more words

Comment: Great! I found especially the link very helpful, which you provided!

Comment: To anyone who wants to turn this option off, the command is `setopt NO_EQUALS`. I'm using the sox audio program and there are valid command line args that start with the equals character.