# "Expected an indented block" What to do?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and don't know what this means. Please tell me what to do to my code for my assessment. It doesn't highlight the problem when I run it and I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: Please share your code than only anyone can assist

Comment: [In Python indention matters](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469458/python-error-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Try reading this post to see how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

In your case, submitting the code you are trying to run will help us better understand your problem instead of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, reading a Python tutorial would probably do you better. In any case, however...

Python is an **indentation-based** language. This means anytime you enter a new "block" (code that belongs to a statement), **you need to indent your code** by one level. Here are two examples, one incorrect and one correct:

```
if 5 < 10:
print "5 is less than 10! Wow! Thanks, math!"
print "I'm so glad Python told me."
```

This is a syntax error, since the `print` statement belongs to the `if` statement, and is therefore a new block. It should be indented, but in this case it wasn't, so it's an error.

```
if 5 < 10:
    print "5 is less than 10! Wow! Thanks, math!"
    print "I'm so glad Python told me."
print "This is printed in any case, since it doesn't belong to the above block."
```

Here is the fixed verion. Notice the four spaces in the beginning of the second line? That's called "indentation". Any subsequent lines indented to the same level will be part of the block. Generally, you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to indent in your text editor. The last line, however, is not indented and will therefore run regardless of whether the `if` statement evaluates to `True` or not.

Comment: While using `TAB` may be the general usage, [PEP 8 (the offical Python style guide) says to use four spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: @leaf Generally you still wouldn't type four spaces manually. Most text editors are configurable to insert spaces upon pressing `TAB`. In case the text editor being used doesn't, it's better to use tabs than to have to manually press `SPACE` 4 times, even if that means not following PEP 8.

Comment: Tab vs spaces is a religious war -- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606988/what-special-meaning-does-an-equal-sign-have-in-zsh

Comment: I believe there is some rationale behind using spaces over tabs. One of the reasons is that the length of a single tab can vary from computer to computer.

Comment: For Python, we thankfully have Word of Guido that 4 spaces should always be used. In any case, it's irrelevant to this question.